# jQuery each loop won't work with json data

Tags: jquery, loops, each

i have a set of jSon data (error-free) wich i need to loop with the $.each function, but it display only the last data record from jSon.

This is the jquery i have for:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/update-recent-stat',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(jsonData)
    {
        var counterjson = 1;

        $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
            var count = counterjson++;
            var link = jsonData[count].linkid;
            var time = jsonData[count].time;
            var value = jsonData[count].value;
            var sender = jsonData[count].sender;

           $("#DownBoxL ul li").html("<div class=Timestamp>"+time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+link+"\">"+sender+"</a> ("+count+") msg sent!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value+"</div>").show();
         });
    }
});
```

So thejSon data are a set with 15 records eg this:

```
[{"counter":"1","linkid":"1448524027","sender":"User1","value":"5","time":"5 sec ago"},{"counter":"2","linkid":"1448524027","sender":"User2","value":"5","time":"5 min ago"}]
```

For the record, with this piece of code it displays only the last record!

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Thanks, regards.

Comment: For the understanding, whats funny there?

Comment: It's JSON like JavaScript Object Notation, but jSon associated me to a Son of Javascript or something like that, not funny now but reading it after 3 cups of coffee was hilarious ;) hard to explain :D but almost spit my 3rd one :)

Comment: Btw you should really consider to accept the answer that most helped you. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overwriting all `li` s HTML every time. You can use `eq` to make the same code work. And use `$.getJSON` it is easy to use for JSON data and it is enough for your requirement.

```
$.getJSON('/jsonurl/file.json', function(jsonData)
{
   var counterjson = 1;

   $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        var count = counterjson++;
        var link = jsonData[count].linkid;
        var time = jsonData[count].time;
        var value = jsonData[count].value;
        var sender = jsonData[count].sender;

        $("#DownBoxL ul li:eq(" + i + ")).html("<div class=Timestamp>"+time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+link+"\">"+sender+"</a> ("+count+") msg sent!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value+"</div>").show();
     });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said, you're repeatedly overwriting, not appending to, the HTML.

In general, however, writing HTML markup from JavaScript isn't a good idea. If, for example, the `sender` string can contain HTML-special characters like `<`, then you've just given yourself a client-side HTML-injection vulnerability.

jQuery gives you some good tools to make direct access to DOM nodes easy. Use them and you can end up with more maintainable as well as more secure code. eg.

```
success: function(jsonData) {
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){
        $('#DownBoxL ul li').append(
            $('<div class="Timestamp">', {text: value.time})
        ).append(
            $('<div class="UserName">').append(
                $('<a>', {href: '#'+value.linkid, text: value.sender})
            ).append(' ('+i+') msg sent!')
        ).append(
            $('<div class="TagValue">', {text: value.value})
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Exception: that's your guess, but it's not always the case that `innerHTML` is a faster way of getting content into a document than DOM calls - it very much depends what you're doing. The case where it makes sense to prepare HTML markup is when you're inserting hundreds of adjacent child nodes at once (typically, rows in a table), and even then you can't (easily/reliably) do an append operation, only replace the lot at once. Until you really, really need to do this, it's best not to, because you have to put a bunch of work into manual HTML-escaping to avoid injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
success: function(jsonData)
{
    var count= 1;
    var htmlData = '';

    $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){

        count++;
        var link = jsonData[count].linkid;
        var time = jsonData[count].time;
        var value = jsonData[count].value;
        var sender = jsonData[count].sender;

       htmlData += "<div class=Timestamp>"+time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+link+"\">"+sender+"</a> ("+count+") msg sent!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value+"</div>";
     });

     $("#DownBoxL ul li").html( htmlData ).show();

}
```

Comment: it seems like he is trying to append the content to `li`s on each iteration. With your code it will append same HTML in all `li`s in `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

value is same as jsonData[i];

```
success: function(jsonData)
{
    var htmlData = '';
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, value){    
       htmlData += "<div class=Timestamp>"+value.time+"</div><div class=UserName><a href=\"#"+value.link+"\">"+value.sender+"</a> ("+ ( i+1 ) +") msg sent!</div><div class=TagValue>+"+value.value+"</div>";
     });

     $("#DownBoxL ul li").html( htmlData ).show();

}
```